# Dynamic Array Behaviour

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please help me understand how these formulas are interpreted differently.

[image]

Question: When I cover Expand formula with `ISNUMBER()` I get `FALSE` for all numeric values (Column G).

However, the same array returns TRUE for all the numerical values when its referenced outside the `EXPAND()` formula( Column F)

Why these different behaviors for virtually a same formula? Note: I have a limited understanding of dynamic arrays, so please excuse me if my question isn't very clear.

Comment: `=ISNUMBER(--EXPAND(A3:A14,,,))` will work.

Comment: @Harun24hr- Thanks but why my second formula works without a double negation ?

Comment: Your 2nd formula is applied to column `E`, not to the original data i.e. `=ISNUMBER(A3:A14)` also yields in all `FALSE`s. The behavior is the same for other functions like `TOCOL`, `UNIQUE`... One could conclude that the data is 'treated' as-is  (blanks are blanks) until it needs to be returned in cells when all blanks are converted to zeros (you can't return a blank in a cell: it's either `0` or *Nothing* (`=""`)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While in array and until printed, those values are actually empty. Try `=ISBLANK(EXPAND(A3:A14,,,))` or `=EXPAND(A3:A14,,,)=""` and you will get `TRUE` for every empty cell in array.
Even simple `=A3:A14=""` or `=ISBLANK(A3:A14)` will return very same array.
So wrapping `EXPAND(A3:A14,,,)` with `ISNUMBER` will not work as those cells are empty.

When "printed" Excel assigns *0*'s to blank values in most cases (if not all, except when you specifically use something like `=IF(A1="","")` and also in this case it is not blank but empty string).
When referring to `E3#` or `E3:E14` you refer to already "printed" cells with those *0*'s and not directly to a result of `=EXPAND(A3:A14,,,)` with empty *values*.

[image]

Why `N` or `--` works is explained by others. It returns *0* on empty cells and *0* is number.

Answer (score 0):

Harun's formula works if you put them together:
[image]

The "--" multiplies all the results of `EXPAND(A3:A14,,,)` twice with `-1` causing the blanks to be treated/calculated as 0's to which the `ISNUMBER` can see it as such (0's).
The letters are therefor not a number as they'll have that #VALUE error you encounter when you take the `--EXPAND` separately.
"--" is very often used to get a numerical answer when dealing with booleans like `SUMPRODUCT`:

[image]

`SUMPRODUCT(A3:A14<>"A")` would just return 0.
`=IF(LEN(A3)>0,XLOOKUP(A3,A3:A14,D3:D14),"NVM")` returns that same 0 vBasic talked about because it's an empty cell, if there were `=""` in D3 for example, it wouldn't be a 0 but also "".